react-native-reanimated: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
Until recently, everything worked until I installed a new dependency react-native-appsflyer.
After which I can't run the project and get this error:
> Task :react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\glebb\Desktop\mately\bemate_app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\q303t1s5\obj\arm64-v8a\libworklets.so.tmp6455ceb'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at C:\Users\glebb\Desktop\mately\bemate_app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\NodeWatcher.js:231:14 {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\glebb\\Desktop\\mately\\bemate_app\\node_modules\\react-native-reanimated\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\q303t1s5\\obj\\arm64-v8a\\libworklets.so.tmp6455ceb'
}

Node.js v20.12.2

besides, after the error I can't delete the node_modules folder without restarting the computer, administrator permission is required (of my Windows profile)
I have already encountered a similar problem and this strange solution in video helped me. But this time it doesn't fix the problem.
I tried all the answers already suggested in React Native - Constant errors like "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat ..."
Suggestion to clear cache in android studio, then reload project, shows another error

On Android Studio go to File>invalidate Caches/Restart
Terminate local react native server
Then Run npx react-native start --reset-cache and npm run android

C:\Users\glebb\Desktop\mately\bemate_app\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewClient.java:314: error: cannot find symbol
        event.putDouble("target", RNCWebViewWrapper.getReactTagFromWebView(webView));
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable RNCWebViewWrapper
  location: class RNCWebViewClient
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
100 errors
only showing the first 100 errors, of 112 total; use -Xmaxerrs if you would like to see more

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

After the offer to execute such commands:

cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx react-native run-android


a similar error appears, but it is related to :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]

Your question requires more details (React Native version, Reanimated version) ?
And are you sure this is related to react-native-appsflyer installation ? Have you tried to uninstall and check if it works again ?

@Layeb ,
"react-native": "0.71.11", "react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1"
I assume that the issue is related to dependencies, as the same error occurred on other computers, but my team and I were somehow able to fix it.
Everything works fine on MacOS.
On one of the computers, there are two projects in different folders—one works, and the other doesn't.
Yes, I tried reinstalling the dependencies.

I solved the problem by creating a new project, installing all the dependencies there and simply copying the android and ios folders into my project.
As a result, you can compare dependencies:
Before
 "dependencies": {
"@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.3.0",
"@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.2",
"@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.13.2",
"@react-native-community/blur": "^4.4.0",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.9.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.9.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.3.0",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"core-js": "^3.36.1",
"dayjs": "^1.11.10",
"jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.11",
"react-native-appsflyer": "^6.14.3",
"react-native-document-picker": "^9.0.1",
"react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^4.0.1",
"react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
"react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.0",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.4.0",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.40.0",
"react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-in-app-review": "^4.3.3",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
"react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
"react-native-permissions": "^3.8.4",
"react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
"react-native-radial-menu": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.8.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
"react-native-screens": "^3.22.0",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
"react-native-version-check": "^3.4.7",
"react-native-webview": "^13.8.1",
"react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
"react-phone-number-input": "^3.4.1",
"react-redux": "^8.1.1",
"redux": "^4.2.1",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
"socket.io-client": "^4.7.2"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.10",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },

Now
  "dependencies": {
"@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.3.0",
"@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.0.0",
"@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.14.1",
"@react-native-community/blur": "^4.4.1",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.2.0",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^20.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^20.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.4.0",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^13.0.1",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.8.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
"axios": "^1.7.7",
"dayjs": "^1.11.13",
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-native": "^0.75.2",
"react-native-appsflyer": "^6.14.3",
"react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^4.0.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.19.0",
"react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.6.2",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.41.2",
"react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-in-app-review": "^4.3.3",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^18.0.0",
"react-native-paper": "^5.12.5",
"react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
"react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.15.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.9",
"react-native-screens": "^3.34.0",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
"react-native-version-check": "^3.4.7",
"react-native-webview": "^13.12.1",
"react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
"react-navigation": "^5.0.0",
"react-redux": "^9.1.2",
"redux": "^5.0.1",
"redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
"socket.io-client": "^4.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.75.2",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.75.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.75.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.35.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^16.1.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1"
  },

Also firebase dependencies required changing files in the android folder (for example build.gradle and others), after which everything worked
